# Is it possible to make two columns work together?

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to make two columns work together?

I have tables which has

```
id |startdate           |length  |enddate
1  |2013-10-10 03:00:00 |60      |2013-10-10 04:00:00
2  |2013-10-11 04:00:00 |40      |2013-10-10 04:40:00
```

When I make new row.
I think enddate is possible to be calculated automatically 
by values startdate and length.

What I want to do is:

1.input two value (length,startdate)
2.enddate is automatically calculated and keep updated.

How can I manage this?

reference:
my doctrine code is like this below

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="startdate", type="datetime")
 */
private $startdate;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="enddate", type="datetime")
 */
private $enddate;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="length",type="integer")
 */
private $length;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use events:

```
/** @PrePersist */
public function updateEndDate()
{
    // this won't work because you need to use DateTime() but just as an example
    $this->endDate = $this->startDate + $this->length ;
}
```

Check: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html#prepersist

and don't forget to put annotation:

```
/** @HasLifecycleCallbacks */
```

Comment: Thank you  I calculated like this       $time = new \DateTime;
$this->toDate = $time->setTimeStamp($this->fromDate->getTimestamp() + $this->length *60);